# Loading a Directory into a Tree Control

Tags: visual-c++

How can I load files and folders into tree control using vc++.
Is any functions available ?

Comment: do you mean file and folder name?

Comment: yes, am trying to do a dialog based program..

Comment: For Eg: I want My Documents as Parent Root. On ClicKing That subfolders and files of mydocuments should be listed

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4472/Enhanced-BrowseForFolder-styled-TreeView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a windows based system you can use the Win32 API [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx), [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions. One small [example](http://vcpptips.wordpress.com/tag/findfirstfile/).

If it is an MFC application you can use [CFileFind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f33e1618%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class. Checkout this example from MSDN.

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Recurse(LPCTSTR pstr)
{
   CFileFind finder;

   // build a string with wildcards
   CString strWildcard(pstr);
   strWildcard += _T("\\*.*");

   // start working for files
   BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(strWildcard);

   while (bWorking)
   {
      bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();

      // skip . and .. files; otherwise, we'd
      // recur infinitely!

      if (finder.IsDots())
         continue;

      // if it's a directory, recursively search it

      if (finder.IsDirectory())
      {
         CString str = finder.GetFilePath();
         cout << (LPCTSTR) str << endl;
         Recurse(str);
      }
   }

   finder.Close();
}
```